# Hibernate save  не синхронизирует БД

Tags: hibernate, java

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    BussesEntity bussesEntity = new BussesEntity();
    bussesEntity.setNumber(1);

    session.save(bussesEntity);
    System.out.println(bussesEntity.getBusId());
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Сущности, натсройки , все валидно. **FlushMode**, по-умолчанию стоит *auto*.
Я в дебагере выполняю код и вижу, что в момент *save()*  база данных не заоплняется.
Она пустая перед работой.
В документации сказано, что должна база изменяться!!! Почему тут это не работает?
Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: А вы транзакцию закрываете после перечисленных манипуляций? Ну и коннекшн тоже вроде закрыть нужно.

Comment: @SuperHuman закрываю, но это не имеет значения